# Add or not to the CV a work experience without a visa

Tags: resume, visa

I would like to ask about a theorical question that could have happened with a friend called Bob.

Suppose that Bob worked with Alice, both from a poor country P and their company had a contract with a customer located in a rich country R that had visa rules similar to the Schengen area where you can stay for 90 days for tourism without a visa.

So, the customer asked for a resource and Alice was alocated to this project. Alice went trough the visa process and, after 3 months, she got the work visa and went to country R. She did a good job there, the customer was happy, but after some months she decided to quit and to move to another company for a better salary/position and gave a 2 weeks notice. The customer was furious because the project deadline was near and they would lose a lot of money if it wasn't completed in time. Fearing suffering penalties, Bob's manager sent him immediately to country R without a work visa and asked him to say in the immigration that he would be 90 days receiving training. So, Bob went there, but was trained only for 1 week, working full time for the rest of the 90 days period, producing new features and generating value, under the "tourist non-visa" rule and not a proper "work visa".

Now Bob is back to his country P and wants to work legally to another company in country R, but is afraid to put in his CV that work experience since a background check could find that he never got a work visa and accepted to work in incorrect conditions.

Question: should he add or not in his CV that he had 3 months of work experience in country R? Considering that the experience/skills that he had there are really important and valued for the company that he wants to impress.

Also, how bad is to tell the truth to a new company that he accepted to work without a proper visa to help his former company?

Comment: I would suggest consulting a lawyer to learn exactly what repercussions Bob might face. It will make picture clearer

Answer (score 6):

> Question: should he add or not in his CV that he had 3 months of work
>   experience in country R?

I would NOT put this in writing anywhere and certainly not on the resume. While well intentioned it's still illegal and there may be serious consequences if the authorities find out. Penalty for these types of violations are often permanent or long term bans and Bob my never be able to enter this country again, if he's found out.

What's done is done, so his best bet is be to make it disappear from all public and private records as quickly and thoroughly as possible. Do not mention it to anyone.

Bob should also talk to an immigration lawyer to find out what the consequences might be and if there is a viable way for him to clear his record without undue burden and punishment. This may or may not be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Don't lie, but don't admit to doing anything illegal. Mention name of your employer and a short technical description of the project you've been working on, without mentioning your location. Working in country R for 90 days wouldn't be a huge plus anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Bob should talk to an immigration lawyer.

It will probably be expensive, but if he does his research and finds a good one then they will understand the nuances of the processes Bob needs to follow in a way that will be hard-to-impossible for Bob to work out for himself.